# CSS :before for small line

Tags: css

I trying to create input, that has `border-bottom` and small (in height) borders in sides like that:
[image: Example]
But this code didn't work:

```
input:before, input:after {
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 1px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

Comment: input do not take pseuddo--element, you need to wrap it inside a span displayed as inlinine-block

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: see beloww for example  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `::after` pseudo element puts the pseudo element inside the element  that you select that, so an input can't have `::before` or `::after`.

Secondly the pseudo element normally requires `content:" ";`

Here is a working example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.input input {
    font-size:20px;
}
.input {
    border:none;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:solid red 1px;
}
.input:before, .input:after {
    content:" ";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    height: 5px;
    width: 1px;
    background: #f00;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input">
<input value="Text" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

so here is my example :

```
span {
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:red solid 1px;
  position:relative;
}
span:before, span:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-1px ;
  height:10px;
  border-left:solid red 1px;
}

<span><input/></span>
```

see it here http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bfDwy

Answer (score 0):

you van also set this by only border css like:

```
border-bottom: red thin solid;
width: 100px;
border-left: thin solid red;
border-right: red thin solid;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
```